# Rails ActiveStorage - without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, rails-activestorage

I have a Feature where user uploads an XML file and the system should read the file and import data. So the file is not attached to any Model Record. So I have a form which allows file input

```
    <%= form_with(
    multipart: true,
    scope: :ctf,
    url:some_path,
    id: dom_id(Import.new, :form),
    data: { turbo: false }
  ) do |form| %>
  <%= render Content::SectionComponent.new do |section| %>
      <span class="text-sm"><%= 'Upload XML' %></span>

        <%= form.label :cf_file, 'File' %>

        <%= form.file_field :cf_file, accept: 'application/xml', required: true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, I get the file as param and manually upload it using ActiveStorage::Blob.

```
    def cf_upload
      importer = Import.new(cf_upload_params)
      if importer.valid?
        file_storage = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(io: cf_upload_params[:cf_file], filename: filename)
        Importers::Cf::ImportJob.perform_later(file_storage)
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = 'Something went wrong'
      end
      render :index
    end
```

Is there any way I can use ActiveStorage direct_upload for this instead of doing upload using ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.htm) `ActiveStorage::Blob` is a database record, and it has been designed with ActiveRecord models in mind.

One possibly viable option for you would be to use [Direct Uploads](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) which essentially allows you to set up some JS so the file is uploaded directly to your storage service (e.g. S3) and what your form submits is a token, or the identifier of the uploaded file.
But this solution is also built on the assumption the `ActiveStorage::Blob` is created. So probably you'd need to hack your way around it.

But if you're asking - can you create the blob and upload it to the service without attaching it to any other model - absolutely. Unatached blobs are a thing, which is why the docs are explaining [how to purge them](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#purging-unattached-uploads) if you want to clean up house.